# Undefind routes. How to solve this problem

Tags: go, path

hope you are doing well. I have a problem with Go "pat" - "https://github.com/bmizerany/pat".

Can anyone tell me where I did a mistake.

**Error:** ***cmd\web\main.go:33:12: undefined: routes***

My *main.go*

```
const port = ":8080"

func main() {
    var app config.AppConfig

    tc, err := render.CreateTmlCache()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("cannot create template cache")
    }

    app.TemplateCache = tc
    app.UseCache = false

    repo := handlers.NewRepo(&app)
    handlers.NewHandlers(repo)
    render.NewTemplates(&app)

    fmt.Println("Starting our port in: ", port)

    srv := &http.Server{
        Addr: port,
        Handler: routes(&app),
    }

    err = srv.ListenAndServe()
    log.Fatal(srv)
}
```

My routes.go.

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/bmizerany/pat"
    "github.com/brosssss/goCourse/pkg/config"
    "github.com/brosssss/goCourse/pkg/handlers"
    "net/http"
)

func routes(app *config.AppConfig) http.Handler {
    mux := pat.New()

    mux.Get("/", http.HandlerFunc(handlers.Repo.Home))
    mux.Get("/about", http.HandlerFunc(handlers.Repo.About))


    return mux
}
```

Comment: try `go run ./dir` instead of `go run ./dir/main.go`

Comment: "I have a problem with Go "pat"" - please state the problem.

Comment: It's unclear from the question if you declare `package main` and your imports in your `main.go` as well. That could lead to it not finding your `routes.go`.